# postgresql: double split data into several columns with subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have this code

```
SELECT 
split_part(oc.created_by, '/', 1) as created_by,
split_part(oc.created_by, '/', 2) as app_version,
split_part(
    (SELECT split_part(oc.created_by, '/', 3) 
    FROM consultations oc), ' ', 1) as os_type,
split_part(
    (SELECT split_part(oc.created_by, '/', 3)
        FROM consultations oc), ' ', 2) as os_version 
FROM consultations oc
```

but I always get

> [Err] ERROR:  Invalid Query:  DETAIL:
>
> ---
>
> error:  Invalid Query:     code:      8001
>
> context:   single-row subquery returns more than one row
>
> query:     30621434    location:  0.cpp:87
>
> process:   padbmaster [pid=27771]
>
> ---

can anyone help me to remove that ?

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

thank you

Comment: *"single-row subquery returns more than one row"*  - That's an Oracle error message for `ORA-01427`. How did you manage to get that in Postgres? Moreover ,without sample data, we may not know what you want and won't be able to provide you a proper solution. So, edit your question and show some sample data and expected output in the tabular format, no images please, only plain text